# simple-oauth2 DEBUG in firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Does anyone knows how to enable debug in firebase functions node environment for an npm package called [simple-oauth2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-oauth2#debugging-the-module)?

The doc says to add `DEBUG=simple-oauth2` as an environment variable but I don't believe firebase functions has a way to set environment variables apart from what is available from `functions.config()`

Any thoughts?

Comment: thanks @MarcAnthonyB, I didn't see it. Ended up setting process.env.DEBUG manually in code (I didn't realize before that one can do that), but the discussion in the link definitely helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with a workaround that might help others too.

`process.env` is just a JSON and you can modify it directly, even though I wouldn't consider it best practice. But it does the job in this specific case.

1: So I ended up adding and hardcoding the `DEBUG` parameter into the `process.env` on the server side before importing the `simple-oauth2` package. Like this:

```
index.js:
process.env.DEBUG = "*simple-oauth2*"
```

2: It appeared one can take more sophisticated and scalable approach by using approach described in this [github thread](https://github.com/debug-js/debug/issues/479#issuecomment-388754557) (thanks to @MarcAnthonyB)

What they do is basically create .env file in your functions and import those variables using `dotenv` package, like below (which internally just modifies process.env json anyway):

```
require('dotenv').config();
```